# AngularJs Manage Cookies

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

In my controller, I have this: 
   $scope.selectedItems = [];

```
        $scope.getElementCart = function (){                                    
                $scope.selectedItems=$cookieStore.get('key');                           
        }
```

and in my html page:

```
<table class="table" data-ng-show="getElementCart ()!=null " >
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>title</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr  data-ng-repeat="elementInCart in getElementCart ()">
            <td><span class="list-asset-item">{{elementInCart.title}}</span></td>

        </tr>
        <tr></tr>   
    </table>
```

it's generate this error :

Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [["fn: $watchCollectionWatch; newVal: 64; oldVal: 63","fn: ......

Comment: The problem might have to do with `$scope.selectedItems.lenght > 0` check. Note that `lenght` is misspelled and since `undefined > 0` is `false` (_obviously_), you get directed to the `else` branch which might be returning a new array (?) every time? Also, note that `getElementCart() !== null` is not likely to work since the function returns `undefined`

Comment: Looks like a cyclical $watch problem where a $watch is updating something that is being watched which in turn is then updating the thing in the first watch.

Comment: Have you got some example???

Comment: @ Bunny: I added the directive to try to manager the error but it doesn't work : : mDirective.directive('dyCart', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            items: '=items'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {         
         element.bind('click', function(){
          scope.$apply();         
         });
        },
        templateUrl: '....'
         
    };
})

Comment: Take the if/else out of the method, remove the method, and just use selectedItems instead of getElementCart(). I imagine the getElementCart() is being called at every digest and doing something funky.

Comment: it works but it doesn't update the list when some element change....